# SVG/iOS - How to use SVGKit?

Tags: ios, ios4, svg

I am trying to include SVGKit (https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) into a test project.

And I get the message:
"libxml/parser.h file not found"

I have checked that the file indeed does not exist on the file system under the project folder.
Neverthe less the demo provided works fine.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Check the build settings. There should be a 'User Header Search Paths' field that must be filled appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add libxml2.dylib into your framework
Then go to Project -> Build Settings and search for "Header Search Paths" key and add this value: "${SDK_DIR}"/usr/include/libxml2 don't forget select "all" for Build settings

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to link libxml to your project. As explained in steps 10 and 11 of "Cross Platform Library Build" on the github page you linked to, just go to Build settings in Xcode, search for "header search paths", double click on it, press the "+" button in the popover, type "/usr/include/libxml2" and make sure "recursive" is selected in the popup button, as I think everything is within yet another subdirectory.
[image: Header Search Paths]

Then add the framework "libxml2.dylib" to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".
[image: libxml2]

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks. These answers are very useful. They helped me move a few step forward. But now ARC seems to be causing a lot of trouble. I first thought that removing a couple of "release", "retain" and "autorelease" ... etc ... would clean the way, but I am not so sure any more. Is there a good (and clean) way to integrate SVGKit in a project using ARC?

Comment: Their readme: ...Linking from an ARC project should not pose an issue, but do let us know if you run into one. If you did not do the cross-compile using our build script mentioned above and did a drag-drop install like some folks like to do, then remember to pass -fno-objc-arc on each of the .m files using the build settings. You can read more about ARC build flags here."